# About to find the maximum sum of transaction within a time window period

Tags: algorithms

I received hundreds of transactions within one week. Each transaction has amount. I'd like to create an algorithm to find the maximum amount within 24 hour time window period. I know how to do that by creating a nested loop. But I am looking for a better performance algorithm such as n*Log(n) time complexity.

For example, the transaction data looks like:

```
[ 
{'05-05-2019:10.00.00', 100}, 
{'05-05-2019:11.00.00', 100},
{'05-05-2019:12.00.00', 100},
{'05-06-2019:10.00.00', 100}, 
{'05-06-2019:11.00.00', 100},
{'05-07-2019:10.30.00', 100} 
]
```

For the above data, there are 6 transactions across 2 days. When calculate the 24 hours period time of transactions, there are 4 time period. The first three transactions happens within 24 hours which has a total amount as 300. The second time period includes three transactions, 2ed, 3rd and 4th  which has a total of 300 amount. The third time period is 3rd, 4th and 5th has 300 amount. The fourth time period is 4th and 5th which is 200. The last time period is the last two which is 200. So the maximum amount is 300.

Comment: I have updated the complexity time which is n*Log(n)

Comment: And (bread & butter) looping through the array of transactions to find the maximum value would not work because...? Note that already has $O(n)$ complexity, which is better than $O(n \log n)$.

Comment: I think that would need nested loops (one for the starting point, the other to see where the 24-hour period ends) which would become something like O(m*n)

Comment: I think If you do a "sliding window" it will take O(n) time : You see each item at most twice, once when you insert it, and once when you remove it.